# what this sign mean in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

i have the following code :

```
 SELECT *
    FROM tbl_doc
      /*_archive*/
      ,
      TBL_LOG@dblink
    WHERE Prim_id='2121212';
```

What is `/*_archive*/` mean  ?
in my database we have :

```
tbl_doc_status
tbl_doc_archive
tbl_doc_save
```

Comment: Isn't that just a comment?

Comment: No isn't, i do not think this comment

Comment: It's a comment. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-5C84C344-CEB3-4DBF-B748-337DE11CCE2A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a /* sequence to the following */ sequence, as in the C programming language. This syntax enables a comment to extend over multiple lines because the beginning and closing sequences need not be on the same line.

MySQL Server supports certain variants of C-style comments. These enable you to write code that includes MySQL extensions, but is still portable, by using comments of the following form:

> /*! MySQL-specific code */

Comment: In English language :).?

Comment: /* is the beginning of the comment and */ is the end of the comment.

Comment: Just to be clear, the question seems to be about Oracle database, not MySQL. Still, the answer is correct.